# Magicbook 14 (amd version) wifi drivers not working realtek 8821ce (SOVLED)

Tags: wifi

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
```

its worked finally

Comment: I haven't needed to try this, but there's [this link](https://github.com/HDUerZhuBin/Realtek-rtl8821ce-Linux-Driver) which has a driver for Linux. I assume you'll need build-essential, which should be easy to install with 'apt-get install build-essential'. I don't recall if it's installed by default on Elementary OS.

Comment: its not working